# facebook app without facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm trying to add sharing for our mobile app and I have created the proper facebook app, custom open graph actions etc but we have decided against using facebook login/register for the moment. Apparently I cannot submit my app for approval to facebook if we're not using the facebook login.

Am I missing something or have we done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to submit your application to the Facebook App Center, which does require login integration per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/ - but this may not be what you're actually trying to do, which I'm guessing is just taking your app out of "sandbox" mode, which does not require anything more than a click.

Answer (score 0):

As per the issue which you highlighted i guess most suitable option for you to create an **"Access Token"** for your **"Facebook App"** and using that **"Access Token"** you can override the login authentication.

Please have look on this article on **"How to crate Access Token?"**: - http://techpost360.blogspot.com/2016/10/create-facebook-access-token.html

Hope it might help you to solve your issue.